# Custom bottom Navigation Design

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement custom curved shape like below left image.

[image: Target]
[image: Achieved]

Below is the code what I have achieved so far by using quadraticBezierTo:

```
        class CustomNotchedShape extends NotchedShape {
          final BuildContext context;
          const CustomNotchedShape(this.context);

          @override
          Path getOuterPath(Rect host, Rect? guest) {
            const radius = 110.0;
            const lx = 40.0;
            const ly = 20;
            const bx = 10.0;
            const by = 50.0;
            var x = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - radius) / 2 - lx;
            return Path()
              ..moveTo(host.left, host.top)
              ..lineTo(x, host.top)
              ..quadraticBezierTo(x + bx, host.top, x += lx, host.top - ly)
              ..quadraticBezierTo(
                  x + radius / 2, host.top - by, x += radius, host.top - ly)
              ..quadraticBezierTo((x += lx) - bx, host.top, x, host.top)
              ..lineTo(host.right, host.top)
              ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom)
              ..lineTo(host.left, host.bottom);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate what the problem is you're encountering. What have you tried yourself? Maybe add the code of the layout you already have, and the part you need help on. Maybe read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use CustomPaint with `Path` and use `quadraticBezierTo` + `archTo` method for curve

Comment: see https://flutterawesome.com/a-flutter-package-implements-a-convex-bottomappbar/